# Network Modem for Gammu Device

Tags: networking, modem, gammu

I'd like to configure Gammu SMS Gateway to work with a network GSM modem. The modem has a LAN IP address.
Is it possible?

The documentation I read only mentions serial/USB connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **socat** in the PC reading the serial-over-IP data from the GSM modem:

```
sudo socat pty,link=/dev/mobile,raw tcp:192.168.1.100:5000&
```